# How can we make an solid object being squashed by another, turning the first one into fluid?

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation, collision

everyone.

My issue is that I don't know how to make an object splatter another.

I have a text appearing on screen [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KaHF.jpg).

I have it recovered by a second text
[in the same manner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrl1O.jpg).

I would love for the first text to be smashed upon impact by the second text and react as it if were paint or any type of fluid, really. This fluid should have a starting shape of exactly the text it imitates, splatter on impact as well as physically reacting to the second text.

I don't (think I) need for the fluid to paint what it touches.

I understand that there should be two instances of my first text, one for coming into frame, the other to be smashed.

But I'm not sure of which physics I should use (namely fluid or dynamic paint) or exactly how to proceed as I fail to fully understand/bend the rules of the tutorials I've watched to adapt to my needs.

Can someone help ?

Also, sorry for not integrating the videos in my post but imgur is doing a number on me, at the time.

Comment: The molecular add-on script should be able to do this.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it.